# Laravel User Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I followed this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

And done with my tabels,

While i try to authenticate, It fails all the time,

I use the default User Model and the auth.php's users table with suggested things in documentation. Should i have to do anything beyond it.

```
  $email = Input::get('email');
  $password = Input::get('password');       
  if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: "it fails all the time". Is that the actual error message you get?

Comment: Can you please show us the error mesasge you are getting ?

Comment: @JosephSilber. ah, not it didn't pass the if condition,

Comment: @Teeyo: I am not getting error message, as i don't how to throw error message here (so i tried with just return statements)

Comment: I fear that should i do anyother stuffs rather than the thing i did ?

Comment: Is the password stored in your database hashed?

Comment: No, it was on plain text @lukasgeiter I can't do it with the plain text password ?

Comment: No don't do that EVER! Going to write an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password you store in your table needs to be a hashed value. Laravel requires it to be. But that shouldn't even be the primary reason. The password needs to be hashed so no one can find out what the actual password is. It doesn't matter if you think your database server is secure and nobody will gain access. There's always a possibility that your database gets compromised and in this case you wan't to protect the users password.

Check [this question on Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords) out for more information on the topic.

Now here's a fast way to get a hashed version of your password. (Without having a registration form, which obviously needs to do that). Add this to `routes.php`

```
Route::get('hash/{value}', function($value){
    return Hash::make($value);
});
```

Open the url `/hash/your-password` and copy this string into the `password` field in your database.

Comment: I can't do this without hashing my password ?

Comment: You shouldn't. And if you want to you need to do a bit more work or write your own Auth UserProvider. Why don't you want to hash your password?

Comment: Well, then i will hash my password,

Comment: It's better that way, believe me.

Comment: Is this the way **$password = Hash::make('secret');** ?

Comment: Or can you suggest the link of laravel way to hash ?

Comment: Exactly that's the way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67732/discussion-between-biz-dev-b-and-lukasgeiter).